# Where to get good old eclipse for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

First time using Android Studio made me want to die, so I think I won't be switching for a while. I want my eclipse back. I only have eclipse workspace backuped after windows reinstall, so where can I get eclipse and all other stuff required? Google removed download links in their website, they only give Android Studio now.

Comment: from the eclipse website. The bundles are still available on the android website

Comment: See this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Open your Eclipse em go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace. Search for "Android Development Tools" in the search input text. Wait until Eclipse load and click on "Install" button.